# odoo : execute python function everytime that the page is refreshed

Tags: python, odoo

How can i execute a python function that brings records from database on Odoo everytime that the page is refreshed , i tried json/rpc but the documentation isn't that clear! please help

this is my function :

```
def _id_facture(self):
    self.env.cr.execute("select max(id) from facturation_facturation")
    id_facture_tuple=self.env.cr.fetchone()
    self.id_facture = id_facture_tuple[0]+1
```

Comment: When you refresh your page, is it something change ?

Answer (score 0):

First, on which version of Odoo are you ?
After, you want to execute your function when which page is refresh ?

Because, i think I've made something as you want to do.

```
def _id_facture(self):
    self.env.cr.execute("select max(id) from facturation_facturation")
    id_facture_tuple=self.env.cr.fetchone()
    self.id_facture = id_facture_tuple[0]+1
```

and, in your XML :

```
<record id="action_xxxxx" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">xxxxxx</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_name_of your_model"/>
    <field name="code">action = env['your.table']._id_facture()</field>
</record>
```

I hope this will help you.